# Installing abpcrawler for Ad Block Plus fails

Tags: python, linux, firefox, windows-7

The biggest problem is likely that I'm trying to install in a Windows 7 environment rather than Linux, but I'm far from certain of this.  Basically one is supposed to have Firefox with Ad Block Plus running & Extension Auto Installer, plus have Python 2.7 installed, before running the following:

```
./build.py autoinstall 8888
```

So since I'm on Windows 7, I opened the command prompt, navigated to the directory & executed the same command without the './' on the front.  I received the following error:

"ImportError:  No module named buildtools.build"

The build.py file is small, so it's not hard to track down the line calling for this.  I still have no idea what buildtools.build is and can't seem to locate anything in the project or online about it.  Does anyone know if doing this on Ubuntu will fix the problem or is it totally unrelated to the OS?  Thank you.

https://github.com/adblockplus/abpcrawler

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I navigated to the Python directory (C:\Python27 for me) in the command prompt and started the command line with "python -vv".  Then I typed "import buildtools" which yielded a list of paths where Python looked for the module.  Each path looked for a .py, .pyd, .pyw, or .pyc file, so I still wasn't sure where to get this file.  Fortunately in the revision history of build.py there was a URL to the buildtools directory, though I didn't know how to turn that into the file it was seeking.  I finally came across a Python tutorial that cleared up the handling of directories as modules for me:

```
The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages
```

(had to code block for the underscores)

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

So all I had to do was download the files & keep them in a directory called buildtools in one of the paths Python was looking in.  I got buildtools in place, found I also had a jinja2 dependency, solved that dependency similarly (though involved an install process for jinja2) and got this working successfully.  Although I doubt anyone will encounter precisely this problem, I hope my groping around for this relatively straightforward Python knowledge will help someone at some point.

Comment: Can you maybe tell us where you find that file? I can't find the URL you are talking about...

Comment: Never mind - found it. For future searchers: https://github.com/adblockplus/buildtools